# busted sd card and pins can you swap out the memory module to a new sd card to recover that chips data

Tags: memory, usb-flash-drive, sd-card

I have an sd card that the pens are trashed-destroyed and the small i would say semiconductor is detached. The information is sooo important for my job. My question is can I buy a new sd card and remove its memory module and swap it out for my module and retrieve the  information off the damaged card? I read in a youtube post that a company in Germany can possibly retrieve the data but it cost hundreds of dollars, that I do not have. Then I came across the above conversation on this site. So desperate teacher looking for a solution. thank you

Comment: If you had the specialized electronics tools required to do this then you wouldn't need to ask the question. Consider using a recovery service, but a local one.

Comment: ...& consider in future that having only one copy of any data, especially on such a disposable medium, is bound to end up in this position sooner or later.

Comment: If a place offers to do it but charges hundreds of dollars, nobody would pay that if it was a simple task; others would do it cheaper.  Are you asking if there is a way for you to do it yourself, or whether there is a cheaper service?  If you looked at it and saw that the silicon is disconnected, did it look like something you have a way to fix?  If you're asking whether there is a cheaper service, that's off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the catch 22...

If you have the skill to do the repair, you would've been able to immediately assess whether it is worth your time, effort, and risk to do so.

This type of repair is complex enough that, if you have to ask and post very vague request for help, with no details of what your problems are and no pictures, the repair is outside your skill level.